# Se puede acceder e ir a buscar una carpeta en específico de otro equipo, por SSH, con un programa Python, que al ejecutarlo se ingrese la IP

Tags: python-3.7, programación-funcional

Necesito crear un programa en **python3**, que al ejecutarlo me deje ingresarle una dirección **IP** y desde esa **IP** (de ese equipo), poder traer un archivo en específico.

Para poder traerlo y de ser posible que se ejecute de manera automática todos los días a determinada hora.

Comment: Sí, seguramente es posible dados los permisos necesarios y las configuraciones de red requeridas. De hecho, si todo eso es para _traer_ un archivo y ejecutarlo, ¿por qué no usar rsync para mantener el archivo actualizado y un cronjob para ejecutarlo?

Comment: gracias, quizas con privilegios de root por ejemplo ?

Comment: @FabiánVaccaro considera que tu publicación se parece mucho a la última que hiciste y que término cerrada (y creo eliminada por ti), por favor lee [ask] y realiza el [tour], si puedes editar y proveer un [mcve] sería estupendo para que la comunidad tenga un punto de donde empezar a ayudarte

Comment: si he visto 3 veces el tutorial amigo, no entiendo por que no puedo preguntar ...

Comment: Preguntar puedes, siempre, pero considera que tu pregunta solo expone la necesidad de realizar algo, pero no agregas que has intentado y sobre esos intentos que dudas puntuales tienes o que errores presenta tu código, por eso no termina de quedar acorde a [ask]

Comment: nose como comenzar a hacerlo, esa es mi duda amigo, necesito ir a buscar un documento, pero no quiero hacerlo por linea de comando. ssh root@ip...   necesito que el programa python lo haga, y que yo ejecute el programa y solo me pida la ip,    por ejemplo ir a buscarlo a /usr/home/carpeta1   etc...

Comment: quizas no se plantear de mejor manera para que se entienda, pero es basicamente un programa en python que al ejecutarlo me consulte una ip, y yo al darle la ip vaya a buscar un documento "x" y lo traiga hacia mi equipo

Comment: En tu pregunta debes de exponer el problema puntual que tienes con tu código, además de proveer un [ejemplo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Si no tienes un código intenta hacer uno. Aquí no se hacen trabajos ni nada, solo ayudamos con problemas en el código que tengas

Comment: Hola, échale un vistazo a `paramiko` una librería de python. Intenta algo y nos comentas los errores que te dé :)

Comment: gracias, estimado, hechare un vistaso